# Tarea crontab linux

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Estoy intentando crear una tarea en LINUX Ubuntu, en donde realizo una consulta a mi base de datos y que despues de eso envie correo con la informacion extraida, el problema es que he buscado en varias paginas y no logro hacer que la tarea de ejecute y envie el correo, el codigo del archivo .SH es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'contraseña';
$db = 'mibasedatos';

$conection = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

if(!$conection)
{
    echo "Error en la conexión";
}

$consulta = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT id_formulario, nombre_usuario, correo_usuario, 
 dd_mm_inicio FROM servicio WHERE id_formulario=7");

if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) 
{
  while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) 
  {                                 
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com';   
    $mail->Username   = 'mi correo';    
    $mail->Password   = 'contraseña de mi correo';   
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom('PRUEBA');
    $mail->addAddress($correo_usuario);
    $mail->Subject = 'inica el curso el dia: '.$fila["dd_mm_inicio"];

        $mail->Body    = 'inicia el curso!';
        $mail->send();

        $mail->clearAddresses();
        $mail->clearAttachments();
      }

      $resultado->free();
```

En mi sistema logro enviar correos pero desde los archivos PHP pero no se como hacer para enviar correo desde archivo .SH

Comment: Algo no me calza, dices que este es tu archivo .sh o un bash de linux, pero yo solo veo código php.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que busque información en algunas paginas y es lo que encontré, te agradecería si me puedes orientar para ver como se hace.

Comment: lo que sucede es que .sh son otros comandos, si ejecutas un .sh solo reconocerá los comandos nativos del lenguaje .sh, si se trata de php es otro lenguaje por lo tanto php solo lo ejecuta el interprete de php, sé que en windows hay un componente CGI el cual ejecuta scripts de php mediante el llamado a dicho script `php script.php` con lo cual se ejecuta, en linux yo creo que de igual manera debe existir algo como eso y en tal caso tu .sh tendría que hacer el llamado al script tal como en windows

Comment: Gracias, intentare con lo que me dices.

Comment: Cambia el shebang a `#!/usr/bin/php`, si es necesario modifica la ruta al ejecutable php. Añade por lo menos la etiqueta de inicio de php `<?php`. Y no olvides que el script necesita permiso de ejecución `chmod +x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas un archivo .sh ni buscar como hacerlos.

Primero cambia todo para que sea como escribieras un archivo php como lo haces en tu servidor web, esto es cambiar la línea de #!/bin/bash y escribir <?php y guarda tu archivo con la extensión php.

Para ejecutar en la terminal de Linux un archivo php, se puede hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
[usuario@host ~]# php "/ruta/a/archivo.php"
```

Por lo que repito no es necesaria la creación de un archivo shell, también puedes poner el path completo del ejecutable de php que comúnmente es /usr/bin/php.

Ahora Linux tiene algo que llamamos crontab, que es la utilería para tareas programadas, comúnmente intentaríamos editar las tareas programadas del usuario con el que estamos loggeándonos con el comando:

```
[usuario@host ~]# crontab -e -u usuario
```

Hay que cambiar la palabra "usuario" por el usuario en el que vayas a crear la tarea programada. Este comando nos abrirá en un editor, ya sea vim o nano, un archivo con la información del crontab del "usuario", en este debes de incluir la información de la tarea programada que quieres crear con parámetros de cuando se debe ejecutar y la ejecución tipo terminal, por ejemplo podrías escribir:

```
59 23 1 12 * php "/ruta/a/archivo.php"
```

Que buscaría ejecutar el archivo.php el primer día del mes de diciembre a las 23 horas con 59 minutos, procedo a explicar que significa la línea campo por campo:

- **59** este número hace referencia a los minutos en el que quieres que se ejecute el comando, podría ser un número de 0 a 59 o asterisco.
- **23** este número hace referencia a las horas en el que quieres que se ejecute el comando, podría ser un número de 0 a 23 o asterisco.
- **1** este número hace referencia al día del mes en el que quieres que se ejecute el comando, podría ser un número de 1 a 31 o asterisco.
- **12** este número hace referencia al mes en el que quieres que se ejecute el comando.
- **asterisco** este dato hace referencia al día de la semana en el que queremos se ejecute el comando, si ponemos un asterisco indica que no vamos a acotar la ejecución del comando por día de la semana, en este dato se puede poner tambien un número del 0 al 6, donde 1 es el día lunes.
- **php "/ruta/a/archivo.php"** sería el comando como si lo ejecutáramos desde terminal.

Podría ponerte otros ejemplos:

```
15 9,12,15,18 * * * php "/ruta/al/archivo.php" > "/ruta/a/archivo/output.txt"
```

Que buscaría ejecutar diario a las 9:15am, 12:15am, 3:15pm y 6:15pm el archivo.php y guardar el output en el archivo output.txt

```
0,30 * * * * php "/ruta/al/archivo.php" > "/ruta/a/archivo/output.txt" 2>&1
```

Que buscaría ejecutar diario cada 30 minutos el archivo.php y guardar el output y las posibles salidas de error en el archivo output.txt

Si no sabes como usar vim, algunos comandos básicos que te puedo dar es que para entrar en edición del archivo hay que usar la tecla "i", para salir del modo de edición se usa la tecla "escape", para guardar se puede ejecutar ":x!" en el modo escape.

Comment: Muestro una guía del uso del cron que incluí en mi blog https://con140.com/2021/09/26/que-es-y-como-funciona-el-cron-en-linux/